# Using regex in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, sql-like

I've run into a problem where I cannot go any longer on my own.
I currently have a database which basically lists my cellphone with different applications on it.

The applications are listed with the status within the same database column which means that i separate the application from the status with a ";" and i separate the different applications with a ",".

Example :

```
ipboard,4.83->6.3,Running;testAcap,6.9-0,Stopped;
ipboard,2.3333->5.366,Stopped;Videostream,1.2,Stopped;
```

Now, how would i go about finding all the ipboards that currently as an app is stopped? As you see, the string before the status can vary in lenght due to the different versions. And I do not want a list of everything that is stopped, just the ipboard in this case.

My crappy query so far that selects all strings with ipboard in them at all(All of them doesnt have it) :

```
select *
  from acaps
  where acaps like '%ipb%'
```

For me the next logical thing to do would be something like :

```
select *
  from acaps
  where acaps like '%ipb%'
  and subshitblabla where "Stopped" after the "," after the ipboard string.
```

Anyone knows how to get this working?

Comment: ... What is your expected output for your sample data?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: how about `select *  from acaps where acaps like '%ipb%' and acaps LIKE '%,Stopped%'`

Comment: `select * from acaps where REGEXP ',Stopped' and REGEXP 'ipboard,'` something like in mysql

Comment: Do you store this data in a single cell single row or you have 2 logs per row, separated with semicolon?
You want result data to have each log to be separate row or to keep same format with filtered out every log that is not stopped ipboard?

Comment: Tried all this, but not really working out. Think I got a tip from a pal I will check out and post here however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for shown interest. Found a sollution that works for me, posting here as reference for others.

```
SELECT * FROM `acaps`
where acaps REGEXP '(ipboard)[,][0-9\-\>\.]*[,](Stopped)\;.*'
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. :) **Edit** Says I have to wait to tomorrow, then I will! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming thar col_name is the coumn taht you wnat use for filter If i remeber correctly you can do it in the same like

```
 select *
  from acaps
  where acaps.col_name like 'ipb%Stopped'
```

Comment: Tried this, sadly however this returns 0. But regardless, if it would "work" would't it flag "Stopped" regardless of it being in the same span as ipb or not? (Separator";")

Comment: the like 'ipb%Stopped' chek if your string start with ipb and end with Stopped .. if you want that return True with Stopped only you should use  OR   operator   `acaps.col_name like '%Stopped' OR acaps.col_name like 'id%'`